# How to make in react-big-calendar different widths for events that overlap each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

What I need to do is that if two events overlap each other in time, the second event would have a width of 65%. How can i do this?

This is screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVLzI.png)

This is my Calendar component:

```
      <DnDCalendar
        formats={calendarFormats}
        components={calendarComponents}
        toolbar={false}
        defaultView="week"
        events={events}
        localizer={localizer}
        onEventDrop={onEventDrop}
        onEventResize={onEventResize}
        resizable
        selectable
        onSelectEvent={onSelectEvent}
        onSelectSlot={onSelectSlot}
        step={15}
        timeslots={4}
        style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 80px)', width: '100%' }}
      />

      const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
```

What have I tried to do:

```
  const eventPropGetter = React.useCallback(
    (event, start, end, isSelected) => ({
      ...(events.filter(e => e.start < end && e.end > start && e !== event).length > 0 && {
        style: {
          width: '65%'
        }
      })
    }),
    []
  )

    <DnDCalendar
        formats={calendarFormats}
        components={calendarComponents}
        toolbar={false}
        defaultView="week"
        events={events}
        localizer={localizer}
        onEventDrop={onEventDrop}
        onEventResize={onEventResize}
        eventPropGetter={eventPropGetter}
        resizable
        selectable
        onSelectEvent={onSelectEvent}
        onSelectSlot={onSelectSlot}
        step={15}
        timeslots={4}
        style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 80px)', width: '100%' }}
      />

   const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
```